# Remove Time from DateTime

Tags: c#, date, datetime, web-applications

I got a `DataTable` that retrieves `DateTime` from `SQL`. However, I want to show *date only* in my `textbox`. I try to convert but *compile time error* keep saying

> no overload for method ToString takes 1 argument.

```
txtexpiry.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"].ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
```

Comment: If you debug and do a quick watch on ```dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"]```, assuming you are using Visual Studio, you will see that it has the type ```object``` and not ```DateTime```.

Answer (score 4):

`dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"]` returns `object`, and that doesn't have that overload. `DateTime` does, so you have to cast the object to `DateTime`:

```
txtexpiry.Text = ((DateTime)dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
```

If the object can be `null`, you have to check that first. The easiest way in this case is to use `is`:

```
 object o = dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"];

 if (o is DateTime d)
 {
     txtexpiry.Text = d.ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
 }
```

Comment: side note: `o is DateTime d` fragment (pattern matching) requires C# 7.0

Comment: Depending againg on the framework version `dtbl.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Safetyexpirydate").ToString("dd/MM/yyy");`

Answer (score 4):

You should `Convert` it and when you get `DateTime` instead of `Object` call required `ToString()`:

```
txtexpiry.Text = Convert
  .ToDateTime(dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"]) // we have DateTime
  .ToString("dd/MM/yyy");                       // which we represent as "dd/MM/yyy"
```

Comment: If it is stored as date, no conversion is needed, only casting.

Answer (score 0):

Convert data row object to `DateTime` and check object for `non-null` condition with simple `ternary (?)` operator before doing type casting.

```
txtexpiry.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"] != null 
  ? ((DateTime)dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyy")
  : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtexpiry.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"]);
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming Safetyexpirydate is already a DateTime type:

```
txtexpiry.Text = ((DateTime) dtbl.Rows[0]["Safetyexpirydate"]).Date
```

Comment: That will still print the time segment when put `ToString`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, Date will return date part without time, as is asking op

Comment: No, it will create a new `DateTime` with the time segment reset to `0`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman As you prefer, but it won't print any time as you said in your first comment.